# pass array values as input in select query in java jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm a beginner in sql and I have a java app connected to a mysql server . In my java app I have an arraylist of ids

```
 ArrayList<String > bookingsToCancel = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to delete all entries in a mysql bookings table I have that have the ids in my table

```
ex. (ids= [1,2] => DELETE *  FROM bookings WHERE id=1 AND  id=2 )
```

but if I had like many ids how could I write my query to delete all entries at once with my ArrayList as input ?

This is an exampe I have in my mind and I am interested to see a different approach

```
 for(String k : bookingsToCancel) { //bookingsToCancel is my ArrayList 
                 String deleteBookings = "DELETE * FROM booking WHERE booking_id = ?";
                 state = conn.prepareStatement(deleteBookings);
                 state.setString(1, k);
                 state.executeQuery();
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    For This Batch Delete with Work 

Below is the code

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try{
    /* Get Preparedstatement object. */
     stmt = dbConn.createStatement();
    
/// for each element of the array add it to preparedStatement
    for(int iteration:ids){
   
                String deleteQuery = "Delete from bookings where id= iteration"; 
                  stmt.addBatch(deleteQuery);
     
            
    
    }
    }catch  (SQLException exception){
            System.out.println("SQL Exception " + exception);{
    }finally{

//When  entire array is exhausted execute it and commit on connection
 stmt.executeBatch();
              
              System.out.println("Batch delete Processing is completed successfully." );
  
             // connection commited
              connection.commit(); 
    }
```